# Why a truck or a plane is "she"?

Tags: pronouns, gender

In trucker forums, I can see drivers referring to their trucks by pronoun  “**she**”. Similarly [a site](http://www.thebomber.com/history/) about an older airplane writes about  “restoring **her**”.

I would expect using “**it**” for all things (which are not persons).

What is the logic here behind using “she” instead of “it”?
In what other cases (not referring to people) is this applied?
Would using “it” sound unnatural in these contexts?

Note: there is already a similar question if a car should be “he” or “she”, but this one is sligthly different.

Comment: related https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/using-she-pronoun-to-refer-to-a-ship and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94954/can-a-ship-or-a-car-be-a-he?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using “she” pronoun to refer to a ship](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/using-she-pronoun-to-refer-to-a-ship)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no grammatical reason for it; it is simply traditional for certain classes of nouns, including

- vessels (*[She'll make point five past lightspeed](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon)*)
- vehicles and other mechanical apparatuses (*[take her out for a spin](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg15521010-800-take-her-out-for-a-spin/)*)
- universities (*[looks she proudly down](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/Far_Above_Cayuga%27s_Waters?View=embedded%27)*)
- nations (*[France and Her Army](https://www.foreignaffairs.com/reviews/capsule-review/1946-10-01/france-and-her-army)*)
- continents (*[A History of Europe, and Her Dependencies, During the Last Four Centuries](https://books.google.com/books?id=Px5kAAAAcAAJ)*)

to be treated as female, especially in literary usage.

Some tie this to personification: Western [national personifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_personification) are overwhelmingly female, for example, as is Mother Nature herself. I think that is reductive, however. England is traditionally personified as *John Bull*, a male, yet the usage was *[England and her allies](https://www.nytimes.com/1860/04/28/archives/england-and-her-allies.html)*. The *USS Andrew Jackson* was invariably a *she*, even if her namesake was a robust adherent of traditional masculine norms. Furthermore, a ship or airplane or city may be called *she*, but the relative pronoun for them will remain *which*, not *who*. Anglophones are not imagining [Marianne](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/france-facts/symbols-of-the-republic/article/marianne) when speaking of France in her multiplicities.

The most common explanation is that institutions and inanimate objects came to be referred to as *she* when perceived as [nurturing or protective, like a mother](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/asithappens/as-it-happens-friday-edition-1.5112374/ships-are-called-she-because-they-protect-and-nurture-like-mothers-says-admiral-1.5113168); they acquired a social gender even if they do not have, and could not have, a biologically-based one. It is not related to grammatical gender, leastways what grammatical gender the Latin *navis* has. English does not have a grammatical gender system any more, and back when it did, *schip* was grammatically neuter.

The use of feminine pronouns with those nouns is increasingly limited, because some see it as patronizing and otherwise outdated.  Given current sensitivities, I'm certain an essay like "[Why We Call a Ship a She](https://www.usni.org/magazines/naval-history-magazine/1998/december/why-we-call-ship-she)" would *never* have been published in a respectable magazine, and coming from a well-respected historian and retired admiral, it would have provoked no small controversy if it had. Even the Scottish Maritime Museum has, to some controversy, [replaced *she* and *her* with *it*](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/ships-gender-neutral-she-scottish-maritime-museum-irvine-a8884346.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing also to special grammatical treatment of this case using *which* not *who*.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a ship "she" is common (perhaps because it caries the crew like a mother?). Countries are often accorded sexuality, e.g. "fatherland" (Deutsche Vaterland) or "motherland" (Russia's Rodina). Speaking of a thing as if it were a living being is, likely, a term of affection.

However, the idioms of a particular group don't necessarily reflect the norm. Perhaps a trucker has a particular attachment to his vehicle, but to most others, a truck's an "it".

Comment: This may be a regional thing (I am from the US) but in casual speech I have often heard men (esp. on TV) refer to their car, motorcycle, boat, sometimes even substantial power tools as "she". It definitely has a limited usage, but I would not say that it is exclusive to truckers.

Comment: @katatahito, Thanks, I stand corrected. As you state, though, it is idiomatic, restricted to a subset of English speakers, and perhaps exaggerated in media fiction.

Comment: +1 after the edits

Comment: The railway locomotive called _Flying Scotsman_ is most definitely a lady, as any British railway enthusiast will tell you.

Comment: And there's *The City of New Orleans*, that Steve Goodman calls "your native son". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJMVj04lfyo Perhaps it's a tougher, American frontiersman ;-) oops, but the Wabash Cannonball is very feminine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZiQ89_s67Q

Comment: Er, Willie Nelson?